# Why won't an object be added to my database

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

So I have that MVVM project with 3 objects(Race, Terrain, Competitor). In order for the app to work I have to create Terrain firs as the other objects refer to it. That is were the problem comes.

The terrain is created via this code

```
        rbtnEasy_CheckedChanged();
        rbtnIntermediate_CheckedChanged();
        rbtnHard_CheckedChanged();
         TerrainViewModel terrain = new TerrainViewModel();

        int countOfPoints = 0;
        int.TryParse(txtControlPoits.Text, out countOfPoints);
        terrain.ControlPoints = countOfPoints;
        if (easy)
        {
            terrain.Diffculty = Difficulty.Easy;
        }
        if (intermediate)
        {
            terrain.Diffculty = Difficulty.Intermediate;
        }
        if (hard)
        {
            terrain.Diffculty = Difficulty.Intermediate;
        }
        TerrainManager.Create(TerrainViewModel.GetModel(terrain));
        UpdateGrid();
        ClearTextBoxes();
        UpdateList();
```

The TerrainManager sends it to the ViewModel

```
public static Terrain GetModel (TerrainViewModel tvm)
    {
        try
        {
            return new Terrain
            {
                ID = tvm.ID,
                ControlPoints = tvm.ControlPoints,
                Difficulty = tvm.Diffculty,
                 
            };

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
```

then to the TerrainDBManager

```
    public static void Create (Terrain item)
    {
        try
        {
            TerrainDBManager manager = new TerrainDBManager();
            manager.Create(item);


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
```

which should add it to the Database

```
 try
        {
            using (ProjectOrienteeringDBContext dBContext = new ProjectOrienteeringDBContext() )
            {
                dBContext.Terrains.Add(item);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
```

I tried to debug it, every thing runs smoothly but after every thing is executed the object can't be found in the database. I checked if the connection to the server is at fault but it too seemed fine.

Comment: add `dbContext.SaveChanges();` after this line `dBContext.Terrains.Add(item);`

Comment: @Barış Can Yılmaz Thanks I didn't realize I had missed the most obvious part.